# Is $[\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C}) \ : \ \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})]$ finite?

Tags: group-theory

when $[\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C}) \ : \ \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})]$ = $|^{\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})} \ /_{ \ \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})}|$ =  $| _{  \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})}$ \ $ ^{\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C})}|$ we need to prove or to contradict that it is finite.

my idea was to use the fact that every $C *\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ can be written as $(A+iB) * \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ for $C\in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{C}) $  and $A,B \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ so that at least one of $A$ or $B$ is in $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$

If someone can give me some guidance that will be  helpful, thanks

Comment: $ \mathbb{C}^*/\mathbb{R}^*$ isn't a finite group ($r e^{i\pi \theta} \mapsto \theta $ is an isomorphism $ \mathbb{C}^*/\mathbb{R}^* \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$, $B\in\text{GL}_2(\Bbb C)$ and that $AB^{-1}\in\text{GL}_2(\Bbb R)$. Then $\det(A)\det(B)^{-1}\in\Bbb R^*$ and
$\det A$ and $\det B$ are complex numbers with the same argument
modulo $\pi$. But there are uncountably many arguments $\det A$ may have,
and so the index in question must be uncountable.

As a follow-up question: is $\text{SL}_2(\Bbb R)$ of finite
index in $\text{SL}_2(\Bbb C)$? This determinant argument won't work!

Comment: $SL_2(C)/SL_2(R)$ is a 3-dimensional real manifold (and in particular is infinite). Also, $SL_2(C)$ has no proper subgroup of finite index.

Comment: But anyway it's immediate that the $e_{12}(it)$, for $t$ ranging over $\mathbf{R}$, are in pairwise distinct left cosets (where $e_{12}(s)=I+sE_{12}$).

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the Baire category theorem that the index is uncountable, since each coset of $\rm{GL}_2(\mathbb R)$ is a closed subset of $\rm{GL}_2(\mathbb C)$ with empty interior.

Same argument holds whenever $G$ is a locally compact topological group and $H$ is a closed subgroup which is not also open, i.e. does not contain a neighborhood of the identity in $G$, in particular when $G$ is a connected Lie group and $H$ is any proper closed subgroup.

Comment: It seems strange to use the Baire category theorem to answer an elementary question.

Comment: Yes, perhaps so.  It's a matter of taste.